Get microphone access for entire browser using chrome extension
i have a chrome extension with manifest v3 and in that i want that when user clicks on a button in popup then user should see a prompt to allow microphone access across entire browser and this should give my extension the access to user's microphone over entire chrome browser but i am not able to achieve this.I have tried writing below code in popup.js--
function getLocalStream() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true })
    .then((stream) => {
      window.localStream = stream;
      window.localAudio.srcObject = stream;
      window.localAudio.autoplay = true;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`you got an error: ${err}`);
    });
}

getLocalStream();

but it gives me permission denied error and it doesn't even show me the prompt to allow or deny access. Anyone any idea about how to handle this functionality??

you can't directly access getUserMedia from a content script due to the security restrictions.  In your manifest.json, make sure you have declared the "media"  permission.
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"scripting",
"media"
],

@NehaChaudhary adding media to permissions makes no difference , also the code is written in popup.js not content script. is there some way so that if user once allows microphone access on any site then microphone access of entire browser gets allowed for my extension??

"make sure you have declared the 'media' permission" - There is no such thing as a "media" permission, according to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions-list

This can't be done. Because cybercreeps.

@O.Jones FYI this can be done because another extension is doing it , i am just not sure how
